# update SMS body, but not Date

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to update body of all sms on Android device with

```
getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values.....
```

query but after request done, also updates message creation/received time.

How i can update message but leave old message date?

I have tried send to update query

```
ContentValues values = sms values oject;
values.put("body", updatedBody);
values.put("date", oldValues.getAsString("date"));
```

but it does not help.

Comment: The `content://sms` content provider is not part of the Android SDK. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Comment: ok, if i can't manage SMS date by "content provider" what alternatives?
 SmsManager can only send messages, but how i can just create and save message to inbox, like sms backup managers does.

Answer (score 0):

I found that getContentResolver().update() with values.put("date"...)
updates SMS date correctly, the only problem is - incorrect displaying date for conversation thread.
If enter into conversation, you'll see correct dates for SMS messages,
after some enter and leave different conversations, android change conversation dates to correct.

The only problem how force updating conversation dates to correct...